# NavMesh baking finished very quickly and does not include some objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am doing one of Unity's official tutorials: Survival Shooter.

Unity version: 5.3.4f1 Device: Macbook, OSX 10.11

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/environment?playlist=17144

The problem: Baking process completes almost instantly and the floor is not highlighted by a blue mesh (where highlight should mean that navmesh is calculated for there).

Here is the screenshot of it:
[image]

Then, I checked the completed scene (which was already created by Unity Team), it showed the floor fully highlighted. I just hit the bake again without touching anything and the same problem happened. So, there must be something else as I tried the original scene file without changing anything.

What am I missing here? Is there a Unity editor setting or something like that which can break the baking process?

Comment: Is the ground set to Static/Static for navigation? (Check the dropdown at the top of the properties panel.)

Comment: Can you post this as an anwer? It solved my problem. The parent was checked as static/static for navigation but it seems like somehow they did not mark it as static for the ground, so I marked it specifically which solved the problem.

Comment: Sure thing! Glad I could help out, expanded the comment to a full answer.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and this answer helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When baking a `NavMesh` for your game, a crucial thing to verify is that every object which should affect navigation is marked as a [Static GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html), or at least Static for Navigation. This setting may be found in a checkbox/dropdown at the top of the properties Inspector:

[image]

It sounds like the floor object in your scene hasn't been marked as Static, meaning it won't factor into the `NavMesh` baking.